# in line 94 of my code it says source not defined but it is?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

```
def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: python degrees.py [directory]")
    directory = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else "large"

    # Load data from files into memory
    print("Loading data...")
    load_data(directory)
    print("Data loaded.")

    source = person_id_for_name(input("Name: "))
    if source is None:
        sys.exit("Person not found.")
    target = person_id_for_name(input("Name: "))
    if target is None:
        sys.exit("Person not found.")

    path = shortest_path(source, target)

    if path is None:
        print("Not connected.")
    else:
        degrees = len(path)
        print(f"{degrees} degrees of separation.")
        path = [(None, source)] + path
        for i in range(degrees):
            person1 = people[path[i][1]]["name"]
            person2 = people[path[i + 1][1]]["name"]
            movie = movies[path[i + 1][0]]["title"]
            print(f"{i + 1}: {person1} and {person2} starred in {movie}")


def shortest_path(source, target):
      """Finds a solution to maze, if one exists."""

        # Keep track of number of states explored
num_explored = 0

        # Initialize frontier to just the starting position
start = Node(state=source, parent=None, action=None)
```

the problem occurs on this line, I checked similar projects and it works, help, this is project 0 on CS50 AI by Harvard, thanks in advance line 94 is the one above this one. part of a document that is supposed to find connections between 2 actors via imdb database

```
frontier = StackFrontier()
frontier.add(start)

        # Initialize an empty explored set
explored = set()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function shortest_path is not correctly indented and exits before reaching that line, so source doesn't exist.

Here is what you should have:

```
def shortest_path(source, target):
    # Finds a solution to maze, if one exists."""
    # Keep track of number of states explored
    num_explored = 0

    # Initialize frontier to just the starting position
    start = Node(state=source, parent=None, action=None)
```

Here is what you currently have:

```
def shortest_path(source, target):
  """Finds a solution to maze, if one exists."""
  # shortest_path ends here

    # Keep track of number of states explored
# This line is NOT in shortest_path
num_explored = 0

    # Initialize frontier to just the starting position
# This line is NOT in shortest_path, source does NOT exist here
start = Node(state=source, parent=None, action=None)
```